# How to View Saved WiFi Passwords on Windows 7, 8, & 10

Tags: windows, passwords, wifi, settings

Can I get the wifi password of my windows pc when it is successful connected? Can I get it from a file or is there another way to do that?

Comment: This is not for criminal purposes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Run CMD
2. Type command : netsh wlan show profiles name=your_network_name key=clear
3. Press Enter

Password will be shown in "Security settings" under the Key Content

Comment: Where are the security settings

Comment: I hace never heard of them. Can i access them without admin previligies?

Comment: When you type this command into CMD there will be text-output and in one line there'll be written "Security Settings"

Comment: Also for for non-admins?

Comment: It's for administrator only. Other way to view it is to enter Sharing and Security Centre in Control Panel and in the network settings click on "Show Password" but this one is also admin-only (there is "shield" next to this option)

Answer (score 0):

Get windows wifi password

Go to the toolbar and select the `Show Hide Icons` button and select the connected wifi 
[image]

Right click on the yellow coloured area and select `Open network & Internet Settings`

[image]

Select the `Change adapter option`
[image]

Then will list all the connections then select the wifi connection which you want to get the password then right click and select the `Status` 
[image]

Then will open a status window and then select the `Wireless Properties`
[image]

after that select the `Security` tab and check the `Show characters` Then you will get the password from the red marked area.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just 2 lines of cmd codes:

```
netsh wlan show profile
netsh wlan show profile <friends-wifi-name> key=clear
```

---

---

`netsh wlan show profile` will show list of wifi-provider names

[image: wifi networks list]

`netsh wlan show profile <friends-wifi-name> key=clear` will show saved wifi details including password at `Security settings > Key Content`
[image: wifi password and details]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get them all in a simple table you can run this "one liner" in a PowerShell window

```
$data =@(); foreach($item in $list) { netsh wlan show profile "$item" key=clear | findstr Key |  ForEach-Object {$row = "" | Select-Object Network,Password; $row.Network = $item; $row.password = $_.Substring(29); $data += $row}}; $data | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Enjoy :)